# Why wc adds plus one

Tags: bash, wc

Lets say I have a word of length `N`.

```
word0=`echo` # N = 0  
word1=`echo A` # N = 1
word2=`echo AB` # N = 2
word5=`echo ABCDE` # N = 5
word4=`echo "ABCD"` # N = 4
```

I use `wc` to get the length of`wordN`, for example:

```
echo $word0 | wc 
   1 
echo $word1 | wc 
   2 
echo $word4 | wc 
   5
```

`wc` adds +1 to the word length and result is `N+1`

Even with `wc -c` or `wc -m` I got `N+1`

Question:  Should `wc` work like this? If so, why it adds +1?

Comment: Those are [useless `echo`s](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo) though; you want simply `word0=''; word1='A'` etc

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try:

```
echo -n "stuff"|wc
```

echo adds a newline, so if you count by `bytes` or `chars`, there is at least 1

see following examples:

```
kent$  echo ""|wc -c
1

kent$  echo -n ""|wc -c
0

kent$  echo  ""|wc -m
1

kent$  echo  -n ""|wc -m
0
```

if you count by "word", there is no difference:

```
kent$  echo  -n ""|wc -w
0

kent$  echo  ""|wc -w   
0
```

Answer (score 2):

My `wc` prints three values: line count, word count and byte count.  I guess yours just prints the byte count.  And the `echo` command you use in the pipe always adds a newline.  That's the additional byte you are looking for.

Comment: Ok, so this is `echo` newline fault?

Comment: `word0` contains 0 bytes, but `echo $word0` outputs the empty string followed by a newline. Try `echo -n $word0 | wc`.

Comment: It's the _reason_, not a _fault_, I would say, yes.

Comment: Or maybe strip that `wc` completely and use `echo ${#word5}` to get the length of the variable value.